# what happens when a Thread throws an Exception?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I invoke the `run()` method on a Thread and the `run()` method throws an **uncaught Exception** what would be the outcome ?

Who catches this *Exception*? Does the *Exception* even get caught?

Comment: To make this more clear - you don't invoke run()  - you call start() on the Thread to make the code in the run() method run in a new thread.  Invoking run() directly just makes the run method execute in the current thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is an exception handler installed for the ThreadGroup, the JVM passes the exception to it. If it's an AWT thread, you can install an event handler for otherwise unhandled exceptions. Otherwise the JVM handles it.

Example of a thread group with a custom handler and how to use it:

```
public class MyThreadGroup extends ThreadGroup {
    public MyThreadGroup() {
        super("My Thread Group");
    }
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable ex) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}

Thread t = new Thread(new MyThreadGroup(), "My Thread") { ... };
t.start();
```

Example of using an AWT exception handler:

```
public class MyExceptionHandler {
    public void handle(Throwable ex) {
        // Handle exception
    }
    public void handle(Thread t, Throwable ex) {
        // Handle exception
    }
}

System.setProperty("sun.awt.exception.handler", MyExceptionHandler.class.getName());
```

Comment: "Otherwise the JVM handles it."  To be more precise, the thread that raised the exception will silently die.

Comment: @Stephen: Actually it prints the exception to stderr.

Comment: Really?  It must be JVM specific then ... because I've been tripped by the absence of a stack-trace.

Comment: Sure, it'll be implementation defined. I wasn't suggesting anyone relies on it. I just meant that it was up to the JVM to decide what to do with unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you've submitted the Runnable to an [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) you can catch the Exception as wrapped inside a [ExecutionException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html). (Highly recommended over simply calling run())

Answer (score 0):

It can if you assign it to a [ThreadGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) that implements the [uncaughtException(Thread, Throwable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) method.